# Java Hibernate C3P0 stored procedure named query error-No operations allowed after statement closed, Unable to release JDBC Connection

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, stored-procedures, c3p0

Facing some weird issues running my stored procedure using `Java`, `Hibernate`, `C3P0`, `named query`, `MySQL`.

**Stored procedure**

```
DELIMITER $$
USE `testdb`;
CREATE PROCEDURE `GetWebUserData`(IN requestId INT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE keyId LONG DEFAULT 1;
    DECLARE name VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT 'testname';

    Select keyId,name;
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

**WebUserData.hbm.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.WebUserData" table="WEBUSERDATA">
        <id name="keyId" type="java.lang.Long">
            <column name="keyId" />
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <property generated="never" lazy="false" name="name" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="name" />
        </property>
        <loader query-ref="GetWebUserData" />
    </class>
    <sql-query callable="true" name="GetWebUserData" read-only="false">
        <return alias="gwud" class="com.WebUserData">
            <return-property column="KEYID" name="keyId" />
            <return-property column="NAME" name="name" />
        </return>
        <query-param name="requestId" type="java.lang.long" />
        <![CDATA[CALL GetWebUserData(:requestId)]]>
    </sql-query>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**Hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">3000</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">3600</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckin">false</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">1</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">10</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.numHelperThreads">25</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">0</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.maxStatementsPerConnection">12</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">1</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_periods">3000</property>

Java version: 8
Hibernate core version: 25.1-jre
Hibernate-c3p0 version: 5.3.1.Final
com.mchange.c3p0 version: 0.9.5.2
MySQL connection version: 8.0.11
```

**Java calling stored procedure**

```
public List<?> callStoredProc() {
    try {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction txD = session.beginTransaction();
        NativeQuery<?> nativeQuery = session.getNamedNativeQuery("GetWebUserData");
        nativeQuery.setParameter("requestId", "1");
        nativeQuery.setReadOnly(false);

        List<?> rows = nativeQuery.list();

        txD.commit();
        session.close();

        return rows;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Issue: When the stored procedure is run for the first time, there is no error. **However, when it is run the second time, below exception occurs at the line**

> List rows = nativeQuery.list();

```
2018-06-23 16:33:47 WARN  org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: S1009
2018-06-23 16:33:47 WARN  SqlExceptionHelper:129 - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: S1009
2018-06-23 16:33:47 ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - No operations allowed after statement closed.
2018-06-23 16:33:47 ERROR SqlExceptionHelper:131 - No operations allowed after statement closed.
2018-06-23 16:33:47 DEBUG org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl - JDBC transaction marked for rollback-only (exception provided for stack trace)
java.lang.Exception: exception just for purpose of providing stack trace
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.markRollbackOnly(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:314)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.markRollbackOnly(TransactionImpl.java:200)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.markForRollbackOnly(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:378)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.handlePersistenceException(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:273)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:150)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:157)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1515)
    at com.mnox.core.hibernate.DatabaseEngine.callStoredProc(DatabaseEngine.java:712)
```

**Alternative #1: I have tried commenting out the**

> `Transaction txD = session.beginTransaction();`

and

> `txD.commit();` lines (i.e: trying calling the stored procedure without a transaction).

However, I get below exception at the line `List<?> rows = nativeQuery.list();`

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to release JDBC Connection
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:149)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:157)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1515)
    at com.mnox.core.hibernate.DatabaseEngine.callStoredProc(DatabaseEngine.java:712)
```

**Alternative #2: I tried commenting out the line “nativeQuery.setReadOnly(false);” just to see the behavior. In that case, below exception occurs:**

```
2018-06-23 17:58:03 DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlStatementLogger - CALL GetWebUserData(?)
2018-06-23 17:58:03 DEBUG SQL:94 - CALL GetWebUserData(?)
2018-06-23 17:58:04 DEBUG org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.ResourceRegistryStandardImpl - Exception clearing maxRows/queryTimeout [No operations allowed after statement closed.]
2018-06-23 17:58:04 DEBUG ResourceRegistryStandardImpl:175 - Exception clearing maxRows/queryTimeout [No operations allowed after statement closed.]
2018-06-23 17:58:04 DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - could not execute query [CALL GetWebUserData(?)]
java.sql.SQLException: No operations allowed after statement closed.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:127)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:95)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:87)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:61)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:71)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:82)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.setString(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1764)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyCallableStatement.setString(NewProxyCallableStatement.java:3687)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.VarcharTypeDescriptor$1.doBind(VarcharTypeDescriptor.java:46)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind(BasicBinder.java:74)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:280)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.sql.NamedParamBinder.bind(NamedParamBinder.java:34)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.bindParameterValues(CustomLoader.java:475)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:2000)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1914)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1892)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:937)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:340)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2689)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2672)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2506)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2501)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:338)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:2223)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.list(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:1053)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.NativeQueryImpl.doList(NativeQueryImpl.java:168)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1506)
    at com.mnox.core.hibernate.DatabaseEngine.callStoredProc(DatabaseEngine.java:711)
```

Comment: Could you please close your session within finally and return your data afterwards and try it out.

Comment: I tried adding this after catch block. finally {
   txD.commit();
   session.close();
  }
  
  return rows;

The issue still exists and fails at rows = nativeQuery.list(); with error "No operations allowed after statement closed.". Note that this issue only occurs when the same code is run for the 2nd time in a loop.

Comment: public List<?> callStoredProc() {
    try {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction txD = session.beginTransaction();
        NativeQuery<?> nativeQuery = session.getNamedNativeQuery("GetWebUserData");
        nativeQuery.setParameter("requestId", "1");
        nativeQuery.setReadOnly(false);

        List<?> rows = nativeQuery.list();
        txD.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally{ session.close();} return rows;
}

Comment: Tried the above suggestion. Results in same exception: 2018-06-29 19:40:06 DEBUG org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.ResourceRegistryStandardImpl - Exception clearing maxRows/queryTimeout [No operations allowed after statement closed.]
2018-06-29 19:40:06 DEBUG ResourceRegistryStandardImpl:175 - Exception clearing maxRows/queryTimeout [No operations allowed after statement closed.]
2018-06-29 19:40:06 DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - could not execute query [CALL GetWebUserData(?)]
java.sql.SQLException: No operations allowed after statement closed.

Comment: Not that i'm sure that it will change anything, but why not use CallableStatement? AFAIK that's the standard way to call stored procedure from JPA

Comment: Are you sharing the session object with any other thread or execution flow. because if you keep on getting the statment close exception then there could be the case.

Comment: Hi Maria, The openSession and session.close() is within the same method and therefore not shared. Also, the test I have performed is to call this method callStoredProc() in a loop and therefore its executing sequentially.

Comment: Hi paranoidAndroid, my idea was to use hibernate ORM with mapping XML files. My stored procedures return about 60 columns in some cases and it is better defined in a XML rather than traversing through each column of the ResultSet in CallableStatement. I have seen many examples of using Named Native Query for stored procedure execution (ex: https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-call-store-procedure-in-hibernate/). I would really like advice to know if hibernate "does not support stored procedure calling via Named native queries".

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate is treating your stored procedure call as a sql query, which it isn't exactly since it is a stored procedure. It looks like it is reusing some state around the query that will cause problems when you use it the second time. Most likely behind the scenes a Statement is opened/closed and then you get a copy of the same statement when you fetch it as a named query.

Try using a CallableStatement instead so that hibernate knows to handle the invocation correctly. Something like this (freehand, not tested):

```
CallableStatment stat = conn.prepareCall("{? = CALL GetWebUserData (?)}");
stat.setString(1, 1); 
stat.execute();
ResultSet set = stat..getResultSet();
...
```

Using a callable statement should prevent any statement reuse.

Comment: Hi Joe...thanks for the insight. Is it correct then to conclude that stored procedures do not work with "named native queries"? I have seen examples from websites such as https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-call-store-procedure-in-hibernate/ which led me to believe otherwise.

The biggest advantage of using XML/POJO is to avoid all that Java code to fetch columns (in my case I have as many as 60 fields returned by stored procedures).

Comment: Hi Joe, Minor correction on the suggestion: registerOutParameter doesn't work since we don't have OUT parameters. Instead we need to use getResultSet. Also, the stat.setString(1, "1"); needs to be replaced with stat.setLong(1, 1);

Comment: Hi Siddarth, makes sense. Did the solution work? I'll update my answer with your notes.

Comment: Hi Joe, I tried this solution. Unfortunately, it appears that my mapping XMLs (hbm.xml) cannot be used. My POJO classes are also rendered useless as I am not able to map the results directly to the POJO. I am looking at plugging these 2 gaps in your suggestion solution and also looking at other alternatives. Will update once I get it working..

Answer (score 0):

Below solution using eclipselink worked for me. I have tested by running this in a loop multiple times. It runs fine without any issues.
https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples

**persistence.xml**

```
<persistence-unit name="mytrial" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <mapping-file>WebUserData.xml</mapping-file>
    <properties>
         <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
         <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/xxxx"/>
         <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
         <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="xxxxxxx"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

**mapping XML file (WebUserData.xml)**

```
<named-stored-procedure-query name="GetWebUserData" procedure-name="GetWebUserData">
    <parameter class="java.lang.Integer" mode="IN" name="requestId" />
    <result-class>WebUserData</result-class>
</named-stored-procedure-query>

<entity class="WebUserData">
    <attributes>
        <id name="keyId"></id>
        <basic name="name"></basic>
    </attributes>
</entity>
```

**Calling the stored procedure**

```
EntityManager em = emFactory.createEntityManager();
EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();
tx.begin();
StoredProcedureQuery spQuery = em.createNamedStoredProcedureQuery("GetWebUserData");
spQuery.setParameter("requestId",IntegerType.INSTANCE.fromString("1"));
List result = spQuery.getResultList();
tx.commit();
em.close();
```